# Função return após EOFError [Python]

Tags: python

Boa tarde,
Preciso resolver o seguinte problema utilizando a estrutura While:

> Dada uma sequência de valores reais, calcular sua média.

O comando dado pelo professor foi:

```
while True:
    try:
        valor = float(input())
        # processar o valor
    except EOFError:
        break
```

E eu desenvolvi o seguinte código:

```
while True:
    try:
        n = input()
        seq_break = n.split(',')
        armazena = 0
        cont = 0

        for val in seq_break:
            armazena += float(n)
            cont += 1
        a = (armazena/cont)
        print(a)

    except EOFError:
        break
```

Entretanto, estou tendo problema com a saída. Ao invés de me retornar a média dos valores (expressa na variável a) ele está me retornando ou todos os valores de entrada ou o último valor. Não sei onde eu estou errando.

Comment: Você está executando esse programa por alguma plataforma que o professor disponibilizou?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está iterando sobre os números armazenados no array `seq_break` com o valor `val` e não com o valor de `n`. O correto seria:

```
while True:
try:
    n = input()
    seq_break = n.split(",")
    armazena = 0
    cont = 0

    for val in seq_break:
        armazena += float(val)
        cont += 1
    a = (armazena/cont)
    print(a)

except EOFError:
    break
```